# Controlling transistor 2 sources

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I want to control the gate or base of a transistor by either a MCU gpio or push button. Can link gate to both the push button and MCU so I can choose which to use. What is best way to do this?

Comment: How is the transistor configured? Specifically, for the MCU?

Comment: As a simple switch that turns on an led. But want to be able manually turn led on with push button or with MCU. Just wanted to know best way of connecting that will have no errors

Answer (score 1):

You can or them into the base like this...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdTkSb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or simply put the switch in parallel with the transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHuzFD.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks only thought of the first solution you gave. Never thought of the parallel setup. Is the diode required

Comment: @JOHNDOE yes and no, without the diode when the MCU is pulling low it will steel some of the current from the switch so the LED will not be so bright. Whether that matters to you I have no idea ;) If you are using a MOSFET the gate voltage would be half so it may not turn on at all.

Comment: @JOHNDOE you would not need the diode if you configured the IO pin as open-source. That is.. pulls high when active, high-impedance when not.

Comment: Ok. Is it better to use a bjt or a mosfet

Comment: @JOHNDOE mosfet wastes less current...

Comment: ok so mosfet it is.

Comment: if i dont have an led and i push the output to a second device for testing purpose what should the resistor value be on the drain

Comment: @JOHNDOE that would depend on what the next device is. 10K would be normal for a logic level.

Comment: @JOHNDOE - If this answer solved your problem, remember to upvote / accept :-)